# The Resource (SQL Server) under resource group was not found

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell, az

When I'm trying to fetch DB in elastic pool getting error as:

> The Resource 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/dbserver.database.windows.net/databases/db_name' under resource group 'rg_name' was not found.

**But for other DB servers and resource group, this script works.**

The script I'm trying:

```
Import-Module Az.Accounts
Import-Module Az.Sql

#Connect-AzAccount -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString <PASSWORD> -AsPlainText -Force
$pscredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('<Application ID>/<Service Principle ID>', $passwd)
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $tenantId 
#-SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

$rg = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName

Set-AzSqlDatabase -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -ElasticPoolName $PoolName -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $serverName 

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit "
```

I verified the permissions, resources and their names/ids all are correct.

Comment: fairly certain that the id is invalid, as the sql server id isnt its dns name

Comment: I'm not using SQL Server ID anywhere, just using DNS name. Which worked for my another subscription

Comment: Have you tried to get the database with PowerShell?

Comment: And is that you want to add the database to the elastic pool ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to add a database to an elastic pool

Comment: Could you please try to use the following script ```$dt = Get-AzSqlDatabase -DatabaseName $DatabaseName  -ServerName $serverName -ResourceGroupName $groupName


Set-AzSqlDatabase -DatabaseName $dt.DatabaseName -ElasticPoolName testpool -ServerName $dt.ServerName -ResourceGroupName $dt.ResourceGroupName``` to implement it?

Comment: Tried using above script but still same error. No change.

Comment: Could you tell me if you can run the command ```Get-AzSqlDatabase -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -ServerName $serverName -ResourceGroupName $groupName```?

Comment: I could not run above command getting same error as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the error message, I can see that you are providing the `-ServerName` as `dbserver.database.windows.net`

Please provide the `-ServerName` as only `dbserver` instead of `dbserver.database.windows.net`

Comment: Thank you for this! Maddening when the error is telling me the server isn't in the resource group, and it obviously IS in the resource group!